# How to specify a number of copies in print lpr command using ssh

Tags: ssh, cat, lpr

When I want to print a document using ssh from my local machine I use

```
cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr
```

This will print my `document.pdf` that is located in my local machine using a printer connected to server.com.

If I want to print the `document.pdf` 5 times I do not know how to do it. I know with `lpr` I need to do `lpr -#5 document.pdf` but how to combine that with `cat` and `ssh`?

I tried

```
cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr -#5
```

and

```
cat path/to/document.pdf -#5 | ssh my_name@server.com lpr
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: Doesn't `cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com "lpr -#5"` work? Or `cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr -\#5`? Or `cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr -\\#5`? Or `cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr -\\\#5`? I can never remember how many backslashes these things sometimes require.

Comment: It worked like this `cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr -\\#5`. Thank you. You can write it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash most likely needs to be escaped, therefore the correct command should be:

```
cat path/to/document.pdf | ssh my_name@server.com lpr -\\#5
```